# Disable Background Scrolling

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am having a asp:LinkButton to show a div on click. On showing the div I want to disable the background page(aspx page) from scrolling. How to do that? I have appplied overflow:hidden; css property to the body. It works fine in the browser but not in mobile devices such as samsung galaxy tablet version-2.2 and sony ericssion version 4.0.4.I want to disable the page scrolling when my application is viewed in mobile.

Please help. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set overflow:scroll; on the body AND the HTML. Also set the position to fixed, position:fixed;.

Comment: just remove the overflow:hidden and try this

Comment: True, but just to make sure that it isn't hidden or if he needs to set it dynamically he can do this.

Comment: @Caleb Keith Thanks for your reply.I have tried. it works perfect.but If we write that inside click function using jquery like **$("body").css({overflow: 'scroll',position: 'fixed'});**
$("html").css({overflow: 'scroll',position: 'fixed'}); **But its not working.I want to disable the scroll in onclick event

Comment: Hi, I am using this code in onload '$("body").css({overflow: 'scroll',position: 'fixed'});'.It disabled the scrollbar.But when I tried to use this code  in click event, its not working

Comment: I found the solution.Thanks for your help.